# JSON Object. Array and variable have same names. How to parse it?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I have below JSON format. Need to parse it. Using below code to parse it. But as you can see in my json there are one variable name hits and one array is dere named Hits. so cod read first "hits" and gives error it is not a json array.

Please suggest how to parse it.

```
JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(fullline);
        JSONArray rows = rootObject.getJSONArray("hits");

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = rows.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONArray elements = row.getJSONArray("_source");

            for (int j = 0; j < elements.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject element = elements.getJSONObject(j);
            JSONObject publisher = element.getJSONObject("publisher");
            JSONObject language = element.getJSONObject("language");

            JSONObject title = element.getJSONObject("title");

            System.out.println("publisher: " + publisher.toString());
            System.out.println("title: " + title.toString());
            }
        }
```

JSON is:

```
{
    "hits": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "_score": 1.4500864, 
                "_type": "journal", 
                "_id": "8f5e8900ffc7431f856ba063a8f1c64c", 
                "_source": {
                    "index": {
                        "publisher": [
                            "Asian Network for Scientific Information"
                        ], 
                        "schema_subject": [
                            "LCC:Agriculture", 
                            "DOAJ:Agriculture and Food Sciences", 
                            "LCC:Plant culture", 
                            "DOAJ:Plant Sciences"
                        ], 
                        "language": [
                            "English"
                        ], 
                        "classification": [
                            "Plant culture", 
                            "Agriculture and Food Sciences", 
                            "Agriculture", 
                            "Plant Sciences"
                        ], 
                        "title": [
                            "Asian Journal of Crop Science"
                        ], 
                        "country": "Pakistan", 
                        "issn": [
                            "2077-2041", 
                            "1994-7879"
                        ], 
                        "homepage_url": "http://scialert.net/jindex.php?issn=1994-7879", 
                        "schema_code": [
                            "LCC:SB1-1110", 
                            "LCC:S"
                        ], 
                        "subject": [
                            "Agriculture and Food Sciences", 
                            "genetics", 
                            "plant physiology", 
                            "Plant culture", 
                            "production", 
                            "Plant Sciences", 
                            "breeding", 
                            "Agriculture"
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "last_updated": "2014-03-09T13:31:38Z", 
                    "admin": {
                        "owner": "16823974", 
                        "in_doaj": true
                    }, 
                    "created_date": "2009-04-30T13:50:33Z", 
                    "id": "8f5e8900ffc7431f856ba063a8f1c64c", 
                    "bibjson": {
                        "publisher": "Asian Network for Scientific Information", 
                        "author_pays": "Y", 
                        "language": [
                            "English"
                        ], 
                        "title": "Asian Journal of Crop Science", 
                        "author_pays_url": "http://scialert.net/guide.php?issn=1994-7879", 
                        "country": "PK", 
                        "oa_start": {
                            "volume": "1", 
                            "number": "1", 
                            "year": "2009"
                        }, 
                        "keywords": [
                            "plant physiology", 
                            "production", 
                            "genetics", 
                            "breeding"
                        ], 
                        "link": [
                            {
                                "url": "http://scialert.net/jindex.php?issn=1994-7879", 
                                "type": "homepage"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "provider": "Asian Network for Scientific Information", 
                        "active": true, 
                        "oa_end": {}, 
                        "identifier": [
                            {
                                "type": "pissn", 
                                "id": "1994-7879"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "type": "eissn", 
                                "id": "2077-2041"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "subject": [
                            {
                                "scheme": "LCC", 
                                "term": "Plant culture", 
                                "code": "SB1-1110"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "scheme": "LCC", 
                                "term": "Agriculture", 
                                "code": "S"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "term": "Plant Sciences", 
                                "scheme": "DOAJ"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "term": "Agriculture and Food Sciences", 
                                "scheme": "DOAJ"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }, 
                "_index": "doaj"
            }, 
            {
                "_score": 1.4500864, 
                "_type": "journal", 
                "_id": "90287ce3214140948d1fc371793da58c", 
                "_source": {
                    "index": {
                        "publisher": [
                            "Bentham open"
                        ], 
                        "schema_subject": [
                            "LCC:Medicine", 
                            "DOAJ:Health Sciences", 
                            "LCC:Internal medicine", 
                            "DOAJ:Medicine (General)", 
                            "DOAJ:Neurology", 
                            "LCC:Neurology. Diseases of the nervous system", 
                            "LCC:Neurosciences. Biological psychiatry. Neuropsychiatry"
                        ], 
                        "language": [
                            "English"
                        ], 
                        "classification": [
                            "Internal medicine", 
                            "Medicine (General)", 
                            "Health Sciences", 
                            "Neurosciences. Biological psychiatry. Neuropsychiatry", 
                            "Neurology", 
                            "Neurology. Diseases of the nervous system", 
                            "Medicine"
                        ], 
                        "title": [
                            "Open Neurology Journal"
                        ], 
                        "country": "United States", 
                        "issn": [
                            "1874-205X"
                        ], 
                        "homepage_url": "http://www.benthamscience.com/open/toneuj/index.htm", 
                        "schema_code": [
                            "LCC:RC321-571", 
                            "LCC:R", 
                            "LCC:RC31-1245", 
                            "LCC:RC346-429"
                        ], 
                        "subject": [
                            "Internal medicine", 
                            "Medicine (General)", 
                            "Health Sciences", 
                            "Neurosciences. Biological psychiatry. Neuropsychiatry", 
                            "Neurology", 
                            "Neurology. Diseases of the nervous system", 
                            "Medicine", 
                            "neurological disorders"
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "last_updated": "2014-03-09T13:31:38Z", 
                    "admin": {
                        "owner": "18740707", 
                        "in_doaj": true
                    }, 
                    "created_date": "2008-05-16T17:41:22Z", 
                    "id": "90287ce3214140948d1fc371793da58c", 
                    "bibjson": {
                        "publisher": "Bentham open", 
                        "author_pays": "Y", 
                        "language": [
                            "English"
                        ], 
                        "title": "Open Neurology Journal", 
                        "author_pays_url": "http://www.benthamscience.com/open/toneuj/MSandI.htm", 
                        "country": "US", 
                        "oa_start": {
                            "volume": "1", 
                            "year": "2007"
                        }, 
                        "keywords": [
                            "neurological disorders"
                        ], 
                        "link": [
                            {
                                "url": "http://www.benthamscience.com/open/toneuj/index.htm", 
                                "type": "homepage"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "provider": "Bentham open", 
                        "active": true, 
                        "oa_end": {}, 
                        "identifier": [
                            {
                                "type": "pissn", 
                                "id": "1874-205X"
                            }
                        ], 
                        "subject": [
                            {
                                "scheme": "LCC", 
                                "term": "Neurology. Diseases of the nervous system", 
                                "code": "RC346-429"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "scheme": "LCC", 
                                "term": "Neurosciences. Biological psychiatry. Neuropsychiatry", 
                                "code": "RC321-571"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "scheme": "LCC", 
                                "term": "Internal medicine", 
                                "code": "RC31-1245"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "scheme": "LCC", 
                                "term": "Medicine", 
                                "code": "R"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "term": "Neurology", 
                                "scheme": "DOAJ"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "term": "Medicine (General)", 
                                "scheme": "DOAJ"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "term": "Health Sciences", 
                                "scheme": "DOAJ"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }, 
                "_index": "doaj"
            }
        ], 
        "total": 9744, 
        "max_score": 1.4500864
    }, 
    "_shards": {
        "successful": 5, 
        "failed": 0, 
        "total": 5
    }, 
    "took": 3, 
    "timed_out": false
}
```

Comment: Go to http://www.json.org/ and don't leave until you've learned what the JSON data types are.

Comment: I'll go ahead and spoil the fun, though: `{` starts an object, `[` starts an array.

Comment: can't just change the JSON property name? or get the first as a JSONObject first then only get the 2nd one as Array, but i think the name is very confusing..